# Arredondar para Cima SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Eu estou fazendo um `SUM(x)` e preciso dividi-lo por `8`, para este exemplo, meu resultado será `5.5`.
O resultado precisa ser como um INT e arredondado para cima.. Então para este exemplo, eu preciso do resultado `6`.

Eu já tentei:

`ROUND(SUM(x)/8,0)`  > Obtive `5`

`ROUND(SUM(x)/8,-1)` > Obtive `10`

`CEILING(SUM(x)/8)` > Obtive `5`

Estou Fazendo isso, o resultado do SUM da 44:

`SELECT ROUND(SUM(x)/8,0) FROM Tabela`

Se fizer com o valor direto, ele arredonda certo:

`SELECT ROUND(44/8,0) FROM Tabela`

Porem preciso que seja com o SUM!

Comment: `CEILING ( numeric_expression )`  deve funcionar. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Como disse, eu já tentei..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faca assim :

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL,ROUND(SUM(44)/8.0,0))
```

Você está colocando a virgula no lugar do ponto. Assim ele entende que é outro parâmetro não o numero.

Comment: Sua resposta não me ajudou a principio, mas tentei fazer uma coisa que vi que você usou que não usei e deu certo : `CEILING(SUM(elrSP18)/8.0)`  `.0` depois do 8 e magicamente arredondou para cima....

Answer (score 0):

Seria isto que você está procurando? Acredito que você esteja fazendo a coisa certa, mas arredondar para cima seria usar a função CEILING.

Fiz um exemplo onde:
SomaPura é o SUM dos meus valores.
ValorDivDois é o SUM dividido por 2 arredondado para cima.
SomaPelaTabelaDivDois é o SUM da tabela dividido por 2 arredondado para cima.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
valor float
)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1.9)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (2.3)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (3.4)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1.8)

SELECT SUM(valor) AS SomaPura FROM @T1

select CEILING(9.4/2) AS ValorDivDois -- 5

SELECT CEILING(SUM(valor)/2) AS SomaPelaTabelaDivDois FROM @T1 -- 5
```

Espero que ajude.